# Can i calculate internet usage by using Wireless Network Connection Status?

Tags: windows-7

Going travelling by bike so want to know how much GB i use on W7 PC per day (for data plans).

So can i just open that panel and add ''bytes sent'' to ''bytes received'' to calculate my usage?

And how to i convert to GB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WiFi Stats will include data exchanged between your computer and the modem / router. Which may or may not be Internet data. Meaning that, your Local Network data and also your Internet data will reflect in those stats. I use Bitmeter II, which does count the same stats(I think!), but gives you a better structured view like hourly, daily, weekly, monthly usage details.

Note: I am not associated with Bitmeter in any way. Its just a very useful program, and is very lightweight.